# What does != 0 mean in this command line -> NR%2 != 0'

Tags: shell, awk

I have tested both of the commands.

```
ls -l | awk 'NR%2 != 0'
ls -l | awk 'NR%2'
```

I saw the difference in the output, but, I do not know how can I explain it when I am teaching it to someone else.

Could you explain to me what `!= 0` means exactly?

Comment: The output should be identical for both commands.

Comment: To help arguing about this, I would use `seq 1 10` to produce the input for `awk` instead of `ls -l`, or add `nl` in the pipe to add line numbers like so: `ls -l | nl | awk 'NR%2'`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Lets say I have skip.sh, skip1, skip2, skip4, skip5, skip6 files and I would like to list only skip.sh, skip2, skip4, skip6. What is the best solution?

Comment: `ls -l skip.sh skip[246]`

Comment: My guess is that you need to teach that someone else about modular arithmetic first. Then it should be easier to explain the AWK part.

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`, the variable `NR` is preset with "the total number of input records seen so far". Thus, when processing the first line it is set to `1`, for the second line to `2`, etc.

The `%` operator calculates the remainder of a numerical division. Thus, with `NR%2` denoting the remainder when dividing the records number by 2, for the first line this computes to `1`, for the second to `0`, for the third to `1` again, and so on.

To determine whether a record is an *odd row* or an *even row*, just check whether `NR%2` evaluates to `1` or to `0`, i.e. `NR%2 == 1` or `NR%2 == 0`. As `1` and `0` are the only possible values, one could also check for the negation of the opposite: `NR%2 != 0` and `NR%2 != 1`, respectively.

In `awk`, a typical instruction consists of a pattern or condition (evaluating to a boolean value) and an action statement. In your case, the action statements are missing, which means the current record should be printed if the condition evaluates to `true`. For convenience, if the condition evaluates to a number instead (as in your second case), the number is automatically cast to a boolean value, with `0` becomng `false`, and any other value becoming `true`.

Therefore, `awk 'NR%2 != 0'` which evaluates to `true` on every other line starting with the first, will print *odd rows* and skip *even rows*. `awk 'NR%2 == 1'` will do the same. And as `1` is cast to `true`, just `awk 'NR%2'` will also do the same.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation. It helped me a lot! Thanks :)